# Mapbox - Get an accurate road route to display on the map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

When we use the directions api over long distances we noticed the lines aren't exactly on the roads, like in this image:

[image]

it's from:
https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/directions/

coordinates: -86.945145,40.090054;-88.26635,40.136585

I didn't find any way to make the directions API return a more precise path but I saw the matching API so I thought I could use the route I got from the directions API and match it to the roads.
The problem is when I use it I encounter the error:

> "All coordinates are too far away from each other"

Even when I try to split the route to pairs of two coordinates it still says that. There's no mention of such a limit in https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#map-matching. The coordinates above return that error.

That's the coordinates I got from directions API so I have no choice but to use them but they're incompatible with matching API, so what can I do to get an accurate directions path that sits exactly on the roads?

I thought about adding midpoints between every pair of coordinates but that won't work in cases where those midpoints would be far off any road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to get more precise geometries from the Directions API:

- `geometries: "polyline6"` (get geometries with 6 decimal places of precision)
- `overview: "full"` (include full geometry in the overview, not just in the route legs)

I think using those will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those. BTW, do you know where there's an example for using the polyline? I looked everywhere in the Mapbox examples and couldn't find it.

Comment: Do I HAVE to convert it to geojson like they did here? https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/route-avoidance-with-turf-mapbox-directions/

Comment: Why don't you experiment and find out.